# military time in script not working

Tags: bash

```
wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null \
| grep PlayerCount \
| head -1l \
| sed 's/^[^>]*>//' \
| sed "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%m\/%d\/%Y %H:%i:%S')/" \
| cut -d">" -f 3,4 \
| sed 's/<\/span>//' \
| awk '{print $3, $4, $1, $2}'
```

outputs:

```
09/19/2012 12:%i:46 99,458 people
```

If I'm not mistaken, isn't %i used for minutes 00-59? Why would it not work? (using cygwin)

Comment: You are thinking of `%M`. Also, this sedding and grepping HTML makes me nervous.

Comment: Worked. Idk why I had little m on there before.

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

You are thinking of %M. Also, this sedding and grepping HTML makes me nervous. –  InternetSeriousBusiness